# python pandas get first digits of column values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, digits

I need to get for each row of a daframe, the first two digits of a number stored in another index (or column after a reset_index()). How can I do it?

My dataframe:

```
        value
index1       
110202      1
223168      5
850484      2
298008      3
950000      6
113500      6
849464      2
849616     10
```

I would like to obtain i.e:

```
                  value
index1 new_value       
110202 11             1
223168 22             5
850484 85             2
298008 29             3
950000 95             6
113500 11             6
849464 84             2
849616 84            10
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `index1` is the index of `df` you could do:

```
df['new_value'] = df.index.astype(str).str[:2]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
        value new_value
index1                 
110202      1        11
223168      5        22
850484      2        85
298008      3        29
950000      6        95
113500      6        11
849464      2        84
849616     10        84
```

Basically convert the column to a string column and then use the [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor to grab the first two characters. For more on working with text data, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html).

As an alternative you could reset the index and access the `index1` column, for example:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['new_value'] = df['index1'].astype(str).str[:2]
print(df.set_index(['index1', 'new_value']))
```

**Output**

```
                  value
index1 new_value       
110202 11             1
223168 22             5
850484 85             2
298008 29             3
950000 95             6
113500 11             6
849464 84             2
849616 84            10
```

Notice that in this alternative solution I set the index as the columns `new_value` and `index1`.

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting this error:

TypeError: Setting <class 'pandas.core.index.MultiIndex'> dtype to anything other than object is not supported

Comment: @user9187374 Updated the answer, please let me know if the alternative works.

Answer (score 1):

make a list from the index with df.index.values
then iterate over the values in this array and grab the first 2 characters